# WSUS get-wsuscomputer cmdlet strange behavior

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get wsus computers with failed state, but instead I get all computers on wsus.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WsusComputer -IncludedInstallationStates All).count
292
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WsusComputer -IncludedInstallationStates Failed).count
292
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WsusComputer -IncludedInstallationStates Installed).count
292
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WsusComputer -ComputerUpdateStatus Any).count
292

PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WsusComputer -ComputerUpdateStatus Failed).count
292

PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WsusComputer -ComputerUpdateStatus InstalledOrNotApplicable).count
292
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-WsusComputer -ComputerUpdateStatus Failed -IncludedInstallationStates Failed
```